# CruiseControl.net build giving the error "The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace" when I add resx resources

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I am building a solution with NANT and CruiseControl.net.  Everything worked fine, then I tried to add in resource files by going into properties and adding one through the resources tab.  Now I am getting the error:

**The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'MyRootNamespace'**

It builds and runs just fine on my local machine, but on our test server, this automated build is crapping out.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

EDIT: Does this require running Resgen.exe in CruiseControl somehow?

Comment: Are you sure you have checked in everything, the new resource file and also the project file?

Comment: All I did was add the resource files through the properties - I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: checked in to source control or where does the test server get the sources from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a resource in this way to a project that does not yet contain any, will create an
 `internal class Resources` in the namespace `MyRootNamespace.Properties`. This class will be placed in a newly created file named `Resources.Designer.cs`
This file will be created in the Properties subfolder. You will need to check this file in into your repository (together with the newly created resources.resx) in order for the build to succeed.

By the way, I am assuming you are using C#, this might be different when you use VB.NET.